# Kotlin: "When statement" skips condition

Tags: android, kotlin

I am trying to validate a form in android using Kotlin. My problem is, that my `when statement` does not work like it's supposed to work. It doesn't check for the other conditions when one is already true.

### Code

```
// It is possible, that both btNumber and ddSalutation are false, but it only checks for btNumber
// and then jumps out
fun isFormValid(): Boolean {
        var error = 0
            when {
                btNumber.value.isNullOrEmpty() -> {
                    btNumberEM.value = emptyFieldError
                    error = 1
                }
                btNumber.value.toString().length < 7 -> {
                    btNumberEM.value = btNumberTooFewChar
                    error = 1
                }
                ddSalutation.value == ddSalutationTextPlaceHolder -> {
                    ddSalutationEM.value = ddSalutationNotSelected
                    error = 1
                }
                etFirstName.value.isNullOrEmpty() -> {
                    etFirstNameEM.value = emptyFieldError
                    error = 1
                }
            }
            return error == 0
    }
```

I hope my question makes any sense. Maybe I didn't understand the `when statements` correctly. Does this maybe not work because of:

> If it is used as a statement, the values of individual branches are
> ignored. (Just like with if, each branch can be a block, and its value
> is the value of the last expression in the block.) ~Jetbrains

I KNOW that there is already the same question but there was no real answer to solve this problem..

I appreciate every help, thank you!

Comment: Indeed, if a condition is true other branches are not checked, that's how `when` works.

Comment: When is replacement of Switch or nested if-else that's how it should work

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`when` works exactly [the way it's supposed to work](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/control-flow.html#when-expression) (emphasis mine):

> `when` matches its argument against all branches sequentially **until some branch condition is satisfied**.

So it executes at most one branch, the first matching one, and then it stops.

If you want to continue to match other branches, just use a series of unrelated `if` statements instead:

```kotlin
// It is possible, that both btNumber and ddSalutation are false, but it only checks for btNumber
// and then jumps out
fun isFormValid(): Boolean {
    var error = 0
    if (btNumber.value.isNullOrEmpty()) {
        btNumberEM.value = emptyFieldError
        error = 1
    }
    if (btNumber.value.toString().length < 7) {
        btNumberEM.value = btNumberTooFewChar
        error = 1
    }
    if (ddSalutation.value == ddSalutationTextPlaceHolder) {
        ddSalutationEM.value = ddSalutationNotSelected
        error = 1
    }
    if (etFirstName.value.isNullOrEmpty()) {
        etFirstNameEM.value = emptyFieldError
        error = 1
    }
    return error == 0
}
```

Comment: Oh, I did not know that, thank you. But one question: Is it possible to skip one of the statements? So lets say if btNumber is Empty I don't want to check if it's length < 7 Should I declare another variable for that?

Comment: Use `if`/`else if`.