# Kotlin function not returning value

Tags: kotlin, return, double

This function is supposed to take a `Double`, `'amount'`, and a `Boolean`, `'international'` and return the shipping cost for an order based on the on the location of the order and the amount.

Code:

```
fun shippingCost(amount: Double, international: Boolean): Double {
    val shipping = when {
        amount >= 75 -> 0.0
        amount < 75 -> amount * 0.1
        international == true -> amount * 0.15
        else -> 50.0
    }
    return (shipping)
}
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val total = readLine()!!.toDouble()
    val international = readLine()!!.toBoolean()    
    println(shippingCost(total, international))
}
```

```
>>> 340.50
>>> true
Returned output: 0.0
Desired output: 50.0
```

Why is the function returning 0?

Comment: Cause `amount >= 75`? The first branch in the `when` gets evaluated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Kotlin: "When statement" skips condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63755176/kotlin-when-statement-skips-condition)